# Rails 3 finding a record based on non-key attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

- I have a model called "Notes".
- The attributes are "id", "url", "content".
- In my notes_controller want to retrieve the "id" of a particular note where the "url" matches my query url.

I am using the following:

```
    @noteid = Note.find(:url => "blah").id
```

However, this returns the error:
Unknown key(s): url

is there a way to find a record based on non-key attributes?

Comment: @meagar: Apparently, a few people benefited from the answer to this question. I sure did. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try
    `@noteid = Note.where(:url => "blah").select('id').id`

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply. This seems to be fetching the record but the problem here is that I get a "String can't be coerced into Fixnum". I tried using to_s to resolve that but that pulls the 8-digit number representing the Object and not just the id attribute. I am new to Rails and I did try looking this up on Google. I would appreciate your help regarding this.

Comment: @rgoraya: I would accept this answer to your question and ask another regarding the "String can't be coerced into Fixnum" issue.

Comment: @ryan: thanks! your comment helps me better understand stackoverflow interaction.

Comment: @Reuben Mallaby It returns an array. You must have missed the `first` part: `@noteid = Note.where(:url => "blah").select('id').first.id`

Comment: Thanks for editing 8) Timezone differences make for late replies!